# Deferred.done not execute chainable process

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

i read the link https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

then i edit my code : as follows

```
 $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'Get',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { id: id },
            url: '@Url.Action("GetInsuranceClaim","Insurance")',
            success: function (da) {
                if (da.Message == "Success") {
                    var d = $.Deferred();
                    d.done($('#Cust_id').val(da.Result[0].customer_id), GetPolicy(), $('#policy_no').val(da.Result[0].policy_detail_id), console.log(da.Result[0].policy_detail_id));
```

> d.done($('#Cust_id').val(da.Result[0].customer_id), GetPolicy(),
>   $('#policy_no option').val(da.Result[0].policy_detail_id),
>   console.log(da.Result[0].policy_detail_id));

GetPolicy() is ajax call my problem is ajax call is executing last,

i required execution order

1. $('#Cust_id').val(da.Result[0].customer_id)

   2. GetPolicy()
   3. $('#policy_no').val(da.Result[0].policy_detail_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code snippet below - note the use of `return` in AJAX calls, it is important to use it so you can chain deferreds.

**Note:** AJAX call is also Deferred!

```
$.GetInsuranceClaim = function(){
     return $.ajax({
                type: 'Get',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { id: id },
                url: '@Url.Action("GetInsuranceClaim","Insurance")',
});

$.GetPolicy = function(){
     //AJAX call - basically the same as the above (don't forget return)
});

$.GetInsuranceClaim().done(function(){
     $.GetPolicy().done(function(policyResponse){
          ///logic you want to do with this response
     }));
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to `Deferred.done()` need to be functions. Your current code executes the three components immediately, and provides the three results to the `done()` method.

You should wrap each argument in a function() { }. Then `done` will call each function in-order.

It may seem that GetPolicy() is executing last. The reality is that it's called second (prior to calling `done()`), it just completes last because it's asynchronous and long.